Ubuntu 24 - no sound from the speakers - LENOVO Legion pro 7
$ lspci -v | fgrep -m1 -A19 '00:1f.3'
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake High Definition Audio Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3846
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 203, IOMMU group 15
    Memory at 6405130000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 6405000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-S PCH SMBus Controller (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3847
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 18, IOMMU group 15
    Memory at 640513c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake SPI (flash) Controller (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3848
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 15

$ uname -a
Linux legion 6.8.0-45-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug 30 12:02:04 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="24.04"
VERSION="24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)"
VERSION_CODENAME=noble

Any clue why is not working out of the box ???

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/Ubuntu-and-legion-pro-7-16IRX8H-audio-issues/m-p/5210709?page=32#6389904
Related

the solution posted here works

Disable audio power saving in the kernel by creating a new file with the

following contents:
Create a new file: /etc/modprobe.d/audio_disable_powersave.conf
Contents:
options snd_hda_intel power_save=0
options snd_hda_intel power_save_controller=N

Apply the fix described here to prevent PipeWire from suspending nodes when there's no audio output.

Create a new file: /etc/wireplumber/wireplumber.conf.d/51-disable-suspension.conf (create the directories if they don't already exist)
Contents:

monitor.alsa.rules = [
  {
    matches = [
      {
        # Matches all sources
        node.name = "~alsa_input.*"
      },
      {
        # Matches all sinks
        node.name = "~alsa_output.*"
      }
    ]
    actions = {
      update-props = {
        session.suspend-timeout-seconds = 0
      }
    }
  }
]
# bluetooth devices
monitor.bluez.rules = [
  {
    matches = [
      {
        # Matches all sources
        node.name = "~bluez_input.*"
      },
      {
        # Matches all sinks
        node.name = "~bluez_output.*"
      }
    ]
    actions = {
      update-props = {
        session.suspend-timeout-seconds = 0
      }
    }
  }
]


restart the computer

